# Were taxes from senatorial provinces and imperial provinces sent to their respective treasuries in the Roman Empire? (Under the rule of Augustus)

Tags: ancient-rome, roman-empire

I read that Augustus imposed a rule that revenue from [imperial provinces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imperial_province) went to the imperial treasury, and the revenue from [senatorial provinces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Senatorial_province) went to the senatorial treasury.

Is there evidence to suggest that the Roman government under Augustus had two separate treasuries and, if so, how were these revenues collected and separated into their respective treasuries?

Comment: Things in separate piles are automatically separated; likewise for separate treasuries.

Comment: "I read that..." - it would help if you included a reference to that source.

Comment: Question seems clear to me. The first Emperor Augustus put some provinces under officials directly appointed by the Emperor, others, as in the Republic came under the authority of the Senate and were governed by former consuls or praetors, (office holders by Augustus' time elected by the Senate). I understand the question to be, did this lead to 2 separate treasuries under different control receiving taxes from senatorial & imperial provinces respectively, or did they all go into one pot? An important and legitimate question re what funds the Emperor controlled to spend on e.g. army & palaces.

Comment: I think it's fair to say that the revised question is now clear in what it is asking.

Answer (score 5):

During the time of Augustus, **there were initially two treasuries until 6 AD when a third one was created**. Extensive changes were made to the operations of state finances during the time of Augustus, but the picture is often not clear, especially in the details. What follows is a summary of (sometimes conflicting) academic sources.

---

**THE ‘TREASURIES’**

- **Aerarium Saturni** (sometimes referred to as the Senatorial Treasury). This was the main state treasury of Rome and was based at the Temple of Saturn, below the Capitol. Under Augustus, it was administered by two praetors (magistrates). Financial records were kept at the nearby Tabularium.
- **Fiscus** (originally meaning ‘money-bag’ or ‘basket’) or Privy-Purse. This is also referred to as the Imperial Treasury in some sources but was not, strictly speaking, a treasury in the the time of Augustus. Rather, it denoted the private funds of Augustus (and subsequent emperors) as well as the financial administration controlled by him. The emperor’s Fiscus was not formally established until the reign of Nero. The term ‘Fiscus’ was also used to refer the funds of provincial governors, though at what point these formally became treasuries is unclear.
- **Aerarium Militare** (Military Treasury). Located on the Capitol, this was established by Augustus in 6 AD. Three senators, effectively dependent upon Augustus, served as prefects of the military fund.

**INCOME**

The sources of the funds of these three financial ‘bodies’ is either not entirely clear and / or varied at different times.

Funds for the **Aerarium Saturni** came from taxes, tributes, customs and various other sources. It certainly included revenue from senatorial provinces and was supposed to have included revenue from imperial provinces. Werner Eck, in *The Age of Augustus*, says

> ...the state treasury (aerarium Saturni), into which all state income,
>   including taxes from Augustus’ own provinces, was declared to flow for
>   legal and accounting purposes.

However, *[The Cambridge Companion to the Roman Economy](https://books.google.com.ph/books?id=Gm7lAgAAQBAJ&lpg=PR4&ots=pwS8P3X2Sg&dq=cambridge%20companion%20to%20the%20roman%20economy%20url&pg=PA79&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=fiscus&f=false)* states

> ...imperial estates in North Africa and public lands in Egypt. All of
>   these lands formed part of a widespread network of properties under
>   the control of the imperial treasury, or fiscus..

This would appear to directly contradict Eck, but we should probably interpret it thus: Eck is saying what should have happened (and maybe did at times) while the Cambridge Companion is saying what actually did happen (at least usually).

For the **Fiscus**, Augustus inherited a vast fortune and this was the foundation of his wealth, but he also ‘diverted’ unknown amounts from imperial provinces into his own accounts, money which should (technically at least) have gone to the Aerarium Saturni.

As Augustus would also sometimes transfer amounts to Aerarium Saturni from his personal fortune when funds ran low, Anthony Everitt’s overall assessment, in *Augustus: The Life of Rome’s First Emperor*, seems appropriate:

> In practice, it was difficult to distinguish between the treasury and
>   the privy purse.

The **Aerarium Militare** was given a ‘starting’ fund of 170,000,000 sesterces from Augustus’ Fiscus. Otherwise, it was financed by two new taxes: an inheritance and large bequests tax of 5% (*vicesima hereditatium*) and a sales tax of 1%. There were also donations from cities and client kings.

**EXPENSES**

The Aerarium Saturni was supposed to cover all state expenses: roads, salaries for the legions, military pensions (up to 6 AD),  public buildings etc, and even those of the emperor,  but Augustus had to step in at times, either transferring money or meeting certain expenses himself. In 20 BC, for example, he effectively took over responsibility for roads (the cura viarum) by transferring money to the Aerarium Saturni. He also paid soldiers pensions out of his personal fortune as the Aerarium Saturni did not have sufficient funds. When the Aerarium Militare was set up in 6 AD, it took over soldiers’ pensions. It appears that Augustus also covered most, if not all, expenses, in the imperial provinces.

As Augustus left considerably less in his will (150,000,000 sesterces) than he had inherited (1,400,000,000 sesterces) we can surmize that, although he apparently diverted income from imperial provinces into the fiscus, these amounts were greatly exceeded by the expenses he covered for the Aerarium Saturni – the military pensions alone were a huge drain on his resources.

**PROVINCIAL TREASURIES**

David Shotter, in *Augustus Caesar*, summarizes their role as

> not so much a deposit of cash as a statement of income and outgoings
>   relating to each province; these accounts were supplemented, where
>   necessary, with grants from the aerarium.

Thus, as Anthony Everitt states,

> ...it is unlikely that large sums of money moved to and from Rome.
>   Each province had its own treasury, from which the princeps would draw
>   for local military and administrative purposes, and in many cases
>   there would not have been a large surplus to send to Rome.

**Other Sources**

*Pat Southern – Augustus*

*Pat Southern – The Roman Army*

*G.W. Bowersock - Augustus and the Greek World*

[*Suetonius - The Life of Augustus*](http://penelope.uchicago.edu/Thayer/E/Roman/Texts/Suetonius/12Caesars/Augustus*.html#101)

[*John Buchan - Augustus*](http://penelope.uchicago.edu/Thayer/E/Gazetteer/People/Augustus/BUCAUG/4/1*.html#note46)

Comment: I don't think Eck and the *Cambridge Companion* are inconsistent. Augustus' personal income from properties in the provinces would not be part of the provinces' taxes. Nor was it state income, and throughout his reign, Augustus maintained the fiction that he was a private individual and not part of the state.